# Ошибка: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android

Добавляю RecyclerView в приложение по [туториалу](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465). Получаю ошибку E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CategoryActivity extends Activity {
    private List<CategoryMenu> categoryMenuList;
    private RecyclerView rv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recyclerview_activity);
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);


        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        initializedData();
        initializeAdapter();

    }

    private void initializedData(){
        categoryMenuList = new ArrayList<>();
        categoryMenuList.add(new CategoryMenu("Sushi", R.drawable.sushicat));
        categoryMenuList.add(new CategoryMenu("Pizza", R.drawable.pizzacat));
    }
    private void initializeAdapter(){
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(categoryMenuList);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Разметка

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cat_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cat_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cat_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Код адаптера:

```
package md.san.suhi.myapplication22;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by opimand on 3/19/2017.
 */

public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.CategoryMenuViewHolder> {
    public static class CategoryMenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        RecyclerView rv;
        TextView catName;
        ImageView catPhoto;

        CategoryMenuViewHolder (View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            rv = (RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv);
            catName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_name);
            catPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_photo);


        }
    }
    List <CategoryMenu> categoryMenuList;

    RVAdapter (List<CategoryMenu>categoryMenuList){this.categoryMenuList = categoryMenuList;}

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public CategoryMenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_activity, viewGroup, false);
        CategoryMenuViewHolder cmvh = new CategoryMenuViewHolder(v);
        return cmvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryMenuViewHolder holder, int i) {
        holder.catName.setText(categoryMenuList.get(i).name);
        holder.catPhoto.setImageResource(categoryMenuList.get(i).photoId);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryMenuList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Разметку в студию

Comment: Добавил разметку

Comment: @Opimand, зачем вы что-то внутрь RecyclerView положили?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я думал он используется как контейнер

Comment: @Opimand, не совсем. Это контейнер для списков данных, в него прямо вот разметку добавлять не стоит. Может в этом и проблема... А может у вас InstantRun, который в настройках студии, сбоит. Попробуйте его отключить

Comment: Действительно, в этом была проблема, исправил, но появилась другая, adapter attached

Comment: Я один не вижу разметку?

Comment: @Flippy, сбивается почему-то после каждого редактирования, сейчас видно